# NSManagedObject changedValues incorrect

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a NSManagedObject subclass that will not correctly update its property.

SCItem.h (relevant part)

```
SCItem : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
```

SCItem.m (relevant part)

```
@dynamic name;
```

- I create a new item with initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext
- Then I set the name: @"name1"
- item.isUpdated is YES
- item.isInserted is YES
- [item changedValues] shows the name changed
- Then I save the context
- The item is correctly persisted
- I set the name again: @"name2"
- item.isUpdated is YES
- item.isInserted is NO
- [item changedValues] is EMPTY
- the item.name logged is correct ("name2")
- Saving the context doesn't persist the name (which is expected because the MOC obviously doesn't know that the value really did change)

I have checked that the item is not being reinitialized (same location in memory). I have also confirmed that the managedobjectcontext stays the same.

I'm new to CoreData. Am I missing something? The only idea I got from searching is to confirm that the subclass still has the property as dynamic, and it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer: I was setting the string based upon an NSTextView's string value. Once I set it to a copy of that value, it worked correctly. The NSManagedObject must have thought that it was being set to the old value because the memory address of the string was the same (I think).